# Segmentation fault while installing OpenCV. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: opencv

I am using instructions from http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/. I have not had any errors except for one error on step 4, specifically the step that says

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

but that hasn't seemed to affect anything. I have checked and the file is there. My issue is when I reach step 5 and I am supposed to put into the console

```
make
```

(because -j4 crashes the pi).

It displays on the console:

```
c++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'm
odules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/perf/cuda/perf_gpumat.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFile/opencv_perf_core.dir/perf/cuda/perf_gpumat
.cpp.o] Error 4
CMakeFile/Makefile2:2253: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_per
f_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could someone help me please! I need this code ASAP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I worked on trying to install it, I found installation instructions on the opencv website, http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation. I was able to successfully install opencv when I followed these instructions.